# Finding Dictionary Key with index number

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing, key

I am attempting to get the Keys in a dictionary

My current method of doing this is using a for loop to iterate through the dictionary. The value of each key is unknown as they are randomly generated.

Dictionary Format for _GENOME[xx][yy].WEIGHTS is {(0,0) : 2, (1,3) : 3}

```
 for i in _GENOME[xx][yy].WEIGHTS:
        print(xx,yy,_GENOME[xx][yy].WEIGHTS[i])
```

I understand my solution will need to use the .index() function. However i can't find a way to implement this into my system.

My hope is to print out each variable of the key tuple separately.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You say you are attempting to get the keys in a dictionary, and the code you posted is doing exactly that. What are you planning to use `.index()` for?

Comment: i'm not looking for the value, i'm looking for the key. As i understand it the key is the tuple in my code and the value is the integer, or am i wrong?

Comment: You are already iterating over the keys... and storing them in `i`. And then you're looking up the value with it even though you say you're not interested in the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help?

```
for key, value in d.items():
    print (("Key - (@1:%s, @2:%s), value - %s ") %(key[0], key[1], value))
```

where d is whatever dictionary object you have (_GENOME[xx][yy].WEIGHTS ?)

Comment: Excellent, this seems to work exactly how I want! is "key" and "value" a function in python? or could i change key and value to... say... x and y? just curious, i like to know how the code i'm using works.

Comment: You can call key and value whatever you want. items() method on dictionary provides these objects to refer to key and values separately

Comment: @ChristianPotts You can change `key` and `value`, as shown here: https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques